# changing button type triggers click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a Button (HTML5):

```
<form id="frmProfileEdit" method="post" action="">
<button id="btnProfileEdit" name="btnProfileEdit" type="button" class="btn">Bearbeiten</button>
</form>
```

In my JS Code, when the document ready event is fired, I register an event handler to the button **once**:

```
var $elem;
function registerProfileFormValidator()
{
    formValidator = $("#frmProfileEdit")
                        .validate(
                            {
                                rules: profileRules,
                                highlight: function (element)
                                        {
                                            $elem = $(element);
                                            $elem.addClass("error");
                                            $elem.parents("form").find('button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                                        },
                                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
                                            {
                                                $elem = $(element);
                                                $elem.removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                                                $elem.parents("form").find('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
                                            },
                                errorPlacement: function () {}
                            }
                        );
}
function profileEditClick(eventArgs)
{
    $('#frmProfileEdit input[type="text"]').removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#btnProfileEdit").text("speichern");
    $("#btnProfileEdit").addClass("btn-success");
    $("#btnProfileEdit").attr("type", "submit");
    $("#btnReset").removeAttr("disabled");
    registerProfileFormValidator();
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#btnProfileEdit").one("click", profileEditClick);
});
```

So, why it triggers the click event after changing the type from button to submit?

I use the plugin jquery validation. For completion, please explore some own rules to the form.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of starting with a `button` and changing it to `submit` after the first click?  It seems like there should be a better way to achieve whatever this is.

Comment: I would like to have a form with input elements, which are disabled on initialization. And then if you click on edit, it should became editable. If you do so, the button should also change into a submit button, so that the user can send the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of the `.validate()` method.

It's purpose is to *initialize* the plugin on your form and nothing else.  It can only be called once because any subsequent call will be ignored.  Once initialized on your form, the operation is triggered ***automatically*** upon various events such as the button click.

Move your entire `.validate()` call outside of any `click` or `submit` handler functions and into the DOM `ready` event handler function.  This will ensure that it's called once; and after the form is constructed.

You also should not have an empty `errorPlacement` function.  If you're trying to disable the placement of errors on the form, you would use a `return false`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $elem;

    formValidator = $("#frmProfileEdit").validate({  // initialize the plugin
        rules: profileRules,
        highlight: function (element) {
            $elem = $(element);
            $elem.addClass("error");
            $elem.parents("form").find('button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            elem = $(element);
            $elem.removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            $elem.parents("form").find('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
        },
        errorPlacement: function () {  // do not leave this empty
            return false;  // disable the default function
        }
    });

    function profileEditClick(eventArgs) {
        $('#frmProfileEdit input[type="text"]').removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#btnProfileEdit").text("speichern");
        $("#btnProfileEdit").addClass("btn-success");
        $("#btnProfileEdit").attr("type", "submit");
        $("#btnReset").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    $("#btnProfileEdit").one("click", profileEditClick);

});
```

Comment: this does not really change anything.

Comment: @alpham8, if nothing else, it should be educational as per the proper way to initialize this plugin.  As far as answering your question, you need to do a little bit of editing on your OP so that people can understand better what you're trying to do.